# Request denied while querying the google places api from my android application

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am building an android application that gets the users location and returns places that are nearby using the google places api.

I have an api key and I am using this url:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false?key=mykey

and I keep getting `REQUEST_DENIED` in my android application. The link works well on the browser and it returns a json.

Comment: Are you using the browser API key, since it works in your browser? You should make one specifically for that Android app, by going to your Google API console, API Access section. If not, I'd like to know whether you fixed the issue, I'm using a valid Android key and still getting my request denied

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a question mark after `sensor=false` instead of an ampersand. Try this instead:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=mykey

Comment: i changed the question mark to ampersand and it is still not working. The link worked well on the browser and i get a json response but not from the andrroid application.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue connecting to the Places API from my android app and receiving the request denied error. The following post resolved my problem. It explains that the Places API does not currently support Android or iOS keys generated from the API console at this time. I will be using the browser key for my app.

[stackoverflow Places API Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem use Browser Key as your key on android.This worked for me. You don't need to fill any thing while creating browser key.