# Google Places API: iOS key: Request Denied

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I'm attempting to query the google places api from an iOS app.  From the google api console I've enabled the Places API in the Services section, and created an iOS key in addition to the default browser key created for me in the API access section. I've assigned the bundle identifier for my app to the iOS key, and hardcoded the bundle identifier in my info.plist to confirm that it matches what I have registered in the Google API Console.

I am attempting to run a test query from my app (referencing Ray Wenderlich tutorial) and receiving a request denied.  I've run the exact same query through my web browser (only difference being the key I'm using - browser key for browser, iOS key for app) and the query is successfully returning results.

At this point I'm assuming the issue is with the setup of my iOS key, or my app bundle identifier.  Is there a different way to debug an iOS app key + bundle identifier other than directly through an app to find out why the request is being denied?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks -
Matt

Comment: Question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/).

Comment: Christ is correct - he verified for me on my Google Group post that iOS specific keys are not currently supported for the Google Places API.  Using the browser key directly in my app queries solved this issue.