# Google places Api Key

Tags: google-places-api, api-key

I have searched through here for other questions related to the same topic and cannot find a definite answer.

My problem seems the same as many others in that I cannot get a response from Google Places Api.

I am trying from within an iphone app, yes the code is correct , I have checked and in desperation just resorted to wiping out the code to just make a request using the examples provided by the Docs on Google Places.

Tried putting the url into a browser, always the same response, whichever browser.

```
{
     "html_attributions" : [],
     "results"  : [],
     "status"  : "REQUEST DENIED"
}
```

I have tried making new keys, same result and yes the identifer for the app is also listed.

Is there a time frame before being able to use the key.

Comment: This will help you :
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a/20796836#20796836)

Answer (score 10):

Here how I've done this

1)You need to login with your google account

2)[Google APi Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) will Appear

3)Look out at Screenshot [image: here]

4)you will find Services over there ,click on it where you can have choose API you would like to use

5)then go to API Access as shown in  [image: this screenshot] you can get your Google API Key.

Thanks

**Advice -use your own Google API key**

Comment: Works for me - I didn't realize I had to use a Browser key.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need 'sensor' parameter in your request URL, I guess.

Just set 'sensor=false&' in the URL and try it.

Comment: The 'sensor' parameter is no longer required. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#Sensor

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the google place API, you need to do the following steps on https://console.developers.google.com:

You need to go your project.

1: Activate Google places API depending upon your clients: iOS, Android or web.

2: Then go to the Credentials section on the left.

3: Generate a SERVER key.

Insert that key into your google place api call. Example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=SERVERKEY

Its a simple GET Rest call.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this
The url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-74.006605,40.714623&radius=5000&types=bar|police&name=&sensor=false&key=Api_key

use this

The url: 
(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-74.006605,%2040.714623&radius=5000&types=bar|police&name=&sensor=false&key=Api_key)

%20 is for space

Comment: and change the location it doesn't have any places search results 
try this ex:  26.175677,%2091.741714 with types = post_office