# Google Places API autocomplete - REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm having a difficult time getting a valid autocomplete response from the Google Places API.  I'm using code based on [their example}(https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) (which, interestingly is using a [seemingly invalid country code of "uk"](https://support.google.com/places/answer/1722104?hl=en#countrycode)).

I have enabled Places API in my Google Code Console.
My API key was generated when I first enabled the Maps API a couple of weeks ago, and the MapFragment I'm using is working perfectly, so I have no reason to suspect that the API key is invalid.

The URL I'm using is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=New+York&sensor=false&key=my_valid_api_key&components=country:us`

I always get `{"status":"REQUEST_DENIED","predictions":[]}` as my response.

I have verified multiple times that my url is formed correctly and adheres to the requirements of the [Places API autocomplete endpoint](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete), yet I do not get the response I'm expecting.

I have seen a number of suggestions of how to fix this on SO and elsewhere, but none of them have worked for me (i.e.-using http instead of https, use port 443, etc.) I have tried these in all reasonable combinations with no change in the response.

Please help me find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a

Answer (score 1):

I tried the URL you provided with my key and it returned the expected results.  I suspect you are using an Android key instead of a Browser key.  Try creating and using a Browser key (under "Simple API Access").

Answer (score 0):

Use the server or browser key instead of the iOS key. Keep the refers field blank to allow all refers.
Here is a sample project which does the same :https://github.com/manishnath/Autocomplete

Comment: Your comment is confusing.  No one has mentioned an iOS key.

Comment: Just trying to give clarity.. I was stuck up using iOS Key and then figured out that is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try this way https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Aus&types=geocode&language=eng&key=your_APIKEY

also refer this like 
http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/

Answer (score -3):

REQUEST_DENIED indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of a sensor parameter.try this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Comment: There is already a sensor parameter being passed.  I am not gathering data from a sensor, so I am passing it as false, as the API instructs me to do.  I've read that page and tried requests similar to the examples already with no success.