# Android google places api return request denied

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

In my Android project I am using Google map v2 and its working. As a change request I need to include search places in AutoCompleteTextview.

```
I did the following steps to get map in Google console.
1) I have registered app.
2) Placed SHA1 key and generated Android key.
3) And made all procedure and get map.

Now I include Google places search in an auto complete textview.
1) go to the project enabled places api in the service pane. (picture 1)
2) I give sample company name and web site url (http://www.google.com). (picture 2)
3) now I get browser key and used it in app. (picture 3)
```

what key need to use (browser key or android app key). I have used both.

But I got Request Denied Exception. I hope I made all things are correct.

I have referred sample from the [site](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/).

screen snaps:

[image]

after that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a/29364238#29364238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using **`Server key`** instead of using brower key.

Answer (score -1):

just add key= before your key value
.Your key should be "key=AIzaSyAVQJO-cp6RcEVUJ-6Yb_b"