# REQUEST_DENIED:: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. error while accessing geocode service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

Invoking the Geocode web service through IBM application server.
and below is the Geocode service URL.
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1601%2BRutherford%2BLn%2CAustin%2C78754%2CTX&sensor=false&key=generated key from google

I have  generated API key, using my machine(where program is running),
I also tried updated with public IP address(This machine is office network).

Any Insight would be appreciated and advanced Thanks

Comment: [It works without a key](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1601%2BRutherford%2BLn%2CAustin%2C78754%2CTX&sensor=false).  There is something wrong with the key you generated.  Is it authorized for the API you are using?

Comment: Generated with Simple API Access, not using Authorized API Access

Comment: you must enable the geocoding-API for the project inside the console when you use a key

Comment: @user3520811 try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a/14744513#14744513

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21933247/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Need to create the public Api key to avoid those error message while access the service.
Refer this link to know how to create the public api key http://hmkcode.com/getting-android-google-maps-v2-api-key/