# Google Directions API failing to return results in iOS

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, ios8, directions

I’m trying to use Google Directions API. I have the SDK all set up. I have enabled **Google Maps SDK for iOS** under the Services in the developer console. Below is the URL I've built to get the directions.

There are two types of keys in the developer console.

[image]

First I tried with the Key for iOS apps.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-37.814107,144.96328&destination=-31.953004,115.857469&key=<Key for iOS apps>
```

But I got the error **This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key**.

When I searched for a solution to this error I saw in a few StackOverflow answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189810/1077789), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20796836/1077789)) that iOS keys are not supported. In the answers they're talking about the Google Places API but I thought it might be the same case with Directions because the error was the same.

So I replaces the *Key for iOS apps* with *Key for browser apps* and ran it again but I got a new error **This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console**.

My question is are there any other APIs I have to activate in the Services to get this working? These are the other map related Google APIs in the list.

[image]

Comment: if you want to “use” Directions.. you have to “activate” in the Google console: "Directions API” , too   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: @TonyMkenu That's it! Now its working. Can't believe I missed that! Thank you. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API "`Google Maps SDK for iOS`" - it is only for integrating the "Google Maps SDK"...

If you want to “use” Directions.. you have to “activate” in the Google console: "`Directions API`” , too [developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/ also there is a nice documentation there.
Yes you need to activate the IOS Maps SDK in the google api center when you log in

Comment: Yes that's the documentation I'm following. And yes, I have already enabled the Google Maps for iOS SDK API. Are there any other APIs I have to activate out of [these](http://i.imgur.com/OzSsq0R.png)?