# iOS Google Maps - search places

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm am developing an iOS map which uses Google Maps to search and display nearby pharmacies. I enabled the following API's: Geocoding API, Google Maps SDK for iOS, Places API.
I created a Browser Key, an iOS Key, and a Server Key.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=MY_KEY",location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection)
{
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

After the connection finishes and with the browser key used:

> "The provided API key is expired."

After the connection finishes and with the app key used:

> "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key."

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Your google search API key expired so create new API key and then try .

Comment: check this link of google for generate google api key https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: i have faced the same problem and i solved my problem from these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a/14744513#14744513  and http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit

Comment: there @moe answer is helped me

Comment: I have a valid API Key which works and the browser key that is not expired.

Comment: Leave the HTTP Refer box empty while creating browser keys..

Comment: https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField