# How to get nearby places using Google map API in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on a Google Map API app. My requirement is i have to find nearby places of a current location.

I share all my codes step by step . please check and let me know what i have to do?

First i create a **Key for browser apps (with referers)**

And enable these below 2 things

[image]
[image]

Then i browse this URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.56666,77.3333&radius=500&sensor=true&types=establishment&key=AIzaSyA5AGzM9KAvTbBbfuoZwQel4XrTrvYoQuo
```

But its showing a error message in browser

```
{
  "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What is the problem i can't understand please anybody can suggest me ?

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: try to Leave the HTTP box refers empty http://stackoverflow.com/a/20796836

Answer (score 1):

Request for a server key and use that with the iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Google Docs carefully before implementing it into your mobile apps.
Click [here for Google API keys doc](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys)

some of the Google API's doesn't support ios & android mobile platforms.

I have attached screenshot as well.[image]

Comment: I can't get u properly @Dipen Panchasara. Please clarify me clearly. what i have to do?

Comment: Key for MAP API doesn't support mobile apps. you can only use it only with Browsers. @SRNayak read documentation for more details.