# Google Places API (Android) LatLongBounds Not Working

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am working on andorid google places api Autocomplete, everything is working fine but when I set custom LatLongBounds to restrict the search to a specific area for GoogleApiClient object, the results returned are not in that bound. I don't what am I doing wrong. This is what I am doing.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(24.85764939832254,67.0641630948748), new LatLng(24.866642601677466,67.07407490512522));
LatLng northeast = bounds.northeast;
LatLng southwest = bounds.southwest;

android.util.Log.e("North-East", northeast.toString());
android.util.Log.e("South-West", southwest.toString());

mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GoogleApiClientHelper.get(getActivity()).getGoogleApiClient(), bounds, null);
mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think Google Place for android is not complete. Api por web works fine, i found a couple web sites where they said you can use this api wor web doing a couple of "fixes" for the code. I think this is not the right way, but if it works, it works.

[Google Places API request denied for Android autocomplete, even with the right api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654758/google-places-api-request-denied-for-android-autocomplete-even-with-the-right-a?rq=1)